# Returning grouped junction table results in a JSON-formatted string

Tags: sql, json, database, sqlite

Say I have a table of people

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Jane |
+----+------+
```

And various tables for clothing of various types, e.g. a table of shoes

```
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
| id |  brand   |        name        |  type   |
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
|  1 | Converse | High tops          | sneaker |
|  2 | Clarks   | Tilden cap Oxfords | dress   |
|  3 | Nike     | Air Zoom           | running |
+----+----------+--------------------+---------+
```

And then I have a junction table, where I’m storing all the clothing that each person has:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| person | shirts | pants | shoes |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 |      3 |       |       |
|      1 |      4 |       |       |
|      1 |        |     3 |       |
|      1 |        |       |     5 |
|      2 |        |     2 |       |
|      2 |        |       |     2 |
|      2 |      3 |       |       |
...
```

I need a query that compiles this junction table into a return like so:

```
+----+------+--------------------+
| id | name |   clothing items   |
+----+------+--------------------+
|  1 | John | [JSON in a string] |
|  2 | Mary | [JSON in a string] |
|  3 | Jane | [JSON in a string] |
+----+------+--------------------+
```

Where the `[JSON in a string]` for each row should look like this:

```
{
  "shirts":[3,4],
  "pants":[3],
  "shoes":[5]
}
```

How do I go about constructing this query in SQLITE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SQLite's JSON Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) to aggregate in the junction table and do a `LEFT` join of `people` to that resultset:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT person, 
         json_object(
           'shirts', json('[' || GROUP_CONCAT(shirts) || ']'),
           'pants', json('[' || GROUP_CONCAT(pants) || ']'),
           'shoes', json('[' || GROUP_CONCAT(shoes) || ']')
         ) clothing_items
  FROM junction 
  GROUP BY person
)
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.clothing_items
FROM people p LEFT JOIN cte c
ON c.person = p.id;
```

I use `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead of `json_group_array()` to remove `null`s.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=f8ad94c21d9b57096c7d4ab7a7561905).

Comment: question - i'm getting a null value instead of an array, e.g. {"shirts":[3,4],"pants":[3],"shoes":null} for keys whenever there are zero of its column for a particular `person` row - is there any easy way I can account for this and have it give me an empty array instead?

Comment: @Nico check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=cc51d401518d50de52f7059c630402a6